# Was Silja Tiedemann aware of her eventual fate when Adam sent her to 1890s?

Tags: dark

In German Netflix series *Dark*, Silja Tiedemann is the

> illegitimate daughter of Egon Tiedemann and Hannah Kahnwald.

Under Adam's orders in 2053, she travels back in time to the 1890s, where she meets and then marries Bartosz Tiedemann.

> She gives birth to two children: Hanno and Agnes. However, she dies giving birth to the second child; Agnes.

It's obvious that Adam had an excellent understanding of the timeline, possibly letting him figure out the eventual fate of Silja even before she traveled back. Did Adam warn Silja about this before she traveled to the 1890s under his orders? Or did he leave her in the dark worrying that piece of info might make Silja stay in 2053 without traveling back?

Answer (score 1):

I don't recall any hint in the series that would actually answer your question. My quess is that Adam didn't mention anything to her, there was no need to. He already knows that it will happen because it already happened, that is how this knot universe works. In a way he couldn't screw this up, the 'knot' allows only the correct (self fulfilling) path.